# Polynomial limit at infinity

Tags: limits

> Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{x^{2n}+a_{2n-1} x^{2n-1}+...+a_0} -x^n =c$ where $a_i$ are rational and $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n$ is a positive integer.

---

The polynomial $p(x)=x^{2n}+a_{2n-1}x^{2n-1}+...+a_0$ is monic and of even degree, hence goes to positive infinity. Also as $p(x)$ is under square root so effectively it's degree is reduced to $n$, which is same as $n$, so I think for infinitely large $x$, they should converge(as they are increasing at same rate. But how do I show it rigorously. Can anyone give some hint

Comment: You can multiply and divide by $\sqrt{\dots}+x^n$

Comment: @SineoftheTime oh, then we get $\infty / \infty$ limit, so we can repeatedly use l hospital?

Comment: L'Hopital is overkill here, just consider the asymptotic behaviour and what term dominates at $\infty$

Comment: @SineoftheTime I have heard of asymptotic behaviour and "domination" but I'm not sure what exactly they are

Comment: then rewrite $x^{2n}+a_{2n-1}x^{2n-1}+\dots a_0$ as $x^{2n}\left(1+a_{2n-1}\frac{x^{2n-1}}{x^{2n}}+\dots+\frac{a_0}{x^{2n}}\right)$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$\begin{align*}
\sqrt{x^{2n}+a_{2n-1} x^{2n-1}+ \ldots +a_0} -x^n &= \frac{a_{2n-1} x^{2n-1}+...+a_0}{\sqrt{x^{2n}+a_{2n-1} x^{2n-1}+ \ldots +a_0} + x^n}\\
&= \frac{a_{2n-1} x^{n-1}+ \ldots + a_n + \ldots +a_0 x^{-n}}{\sqrt{1 +a_{2n-1} x^{-1}+...+a_0 x^{-2n}} + 1}
\end{align*}$$